# Why are my DVD disks in the wrong format?

Tags: optical-drive, dvd, disk-format

I'm trying to play DVDs on my MacBook Pro however the disk doesn't play it doesn't even mount.

When I check Disk Utility it shows the format as Windows NTFS 3G.

If I try the same disks on another macbook it shows as Universal Disk Format (UDF) and plays fine.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Do other discs work in that drive?  A normal music CD for example?

Comment: Yes music CDs and software disks are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears Parallels is the cause of the issue.  Found some instructions on [paragon-software.com](http://kb.paragon-software.com/paragon/include/templ/object2.jsp?catId=2124&objId=6879&statId=1694444&foLang=en) and executed step 1. DVDs now working great!

Comment: Glad you worked this one out. It was a real head scratcher.